# Button activated div slide goes under instead of over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to build an interface where when you click a button a full sized div with all it's content fills up the whole screen. There are two sliding divs, it works one way, but the other way the div slides under the first div.

I was attempting to use toggle - and switch to a css that increases the DIVS width property to take over the screen.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Here is my code and a fiddle at the bottom:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<div class="one">
<a href="#"><div class="openone">
<div class="vertical-text-one">OPEN ONE</div>
 </div></a>
ONE</div></div>
<div class="right">
<div class="two">
<a href="#"><div class="opentwo">
<div class="vertical-text-two">OPEN TWO</div>
</div></a>TWO
</div></div>
<div class="header" >
TOP
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.openone').click(function(e){
$('.left').toggleClass('clicked');
});
$('.opentwo').click(function(e){
$('.right').toggleClass('clicked');
});
});
```

CSS snippet:

```
.left{
background-color: #06C;
width:50%;
height: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
z-index: 1;
transition: width 1s;

}
.left.clicked {
width: 98%; 
background-color: #06C;
z-index: 100;

}
.right{
background-color: #3AD;
float:right;
width:50%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
transition: width 1s;
}
.right.clicked {
width: 98%;
background-color: #3AD;
z-index: 100;
overflow: hidden;
}
.two{
position:absolute;
top: 110px; 
}
.one{
position:absolute;
top: 110px;
}
.openone {
position: relative;
height: 50%;
width:200px;
background-color: #06C;
left: 101%;
}

.opentwo {
position: relative;
height: 50%;
width:200px;
background-color: #3AD;
left: 0px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hmyLrzta/19/

Comment: Probably something to do with you defining a z-index only for .right.clicked. However, you should try to accomplish this playing with "display: none" to hide the div and "display: block" to show the div

Answer (score 0):

Just expand your coding with this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.openone').click(function(e){
        $('.left').toggleClass('clicked');
        $('.right').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
    $('.opentwo').click(function(e){
        $('.right').toggleClass('clicked');
        $('.left').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

This will render the not active panel invisible using `display: none;`

http://jsfiddle.net/hmyLrzta/21/